rtl8812au-dkms Error during upgrade Ubuntu 24.04
How to solve this problem?
When I wright this command "sudo apt-get upgrade" to upgrade the app. the following error is shown up in the end of the result:

Setting up rtl8812au-dkms (4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu22) ...
Removing old rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg DKMS files...
Deleting module rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-35-generic
Building initial module for 6.8.0-35-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtl8812au-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-35-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8812au-dkms (--configure):
installed rtl8812au-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
rtl8812au-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Where is the clear concise question?

I just added it.

Have you consulted the /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/make.log for more information as suggested?

that file could not help me to solve the issue.

Could edit your question to clarify what your problem is, and if @david's answer below resolved your problem to up vote and mark it as a solution.  Or if it did not, then to clarify what the further issue is.

I build a driver for at least a very similar (8821au vs 8812au) WIFI stick. (The standard Ubuntu driver for my stick has not worked for some time so I build a custom one. See...
https://github.com/morrownr
I think yours is on this.
(Note: I did a fresh install and not upgrade so there might be rules about removing old drivers before adding new ones - I don't know.)
I did notice on 24.04 my current (common /home with 22.04) driver did not build so I pulled the sources again (from above) and even though the target has a date encoded into the name which has not changed it seems to have been updated and works with the new pull on 24.04 & 22.04.
Thought this might be of some help.

Now works but still reports errors?
Possibly you did not remove (from dkms) the old version of the driver before installing the new one. If they have different names you might have ended up with both installed in dkms. (The initial driver cannot be installed because it can't built it but dkms might still be trying to build it.)
Your original driver source could/will have an uninstall script you could try but there is a danger it could also remove the successfully built one. If that happened you could then just re-install the good one.
What does dkms status report?
Remember it will report for each historic or current kernel (you can still boot from one of these) it has been built for so expect more than one.
The following gives details of dkms and how to uninstall modules.
How do I uninstall dkms modules if there are two of them?
Hope this is of some help

Now I can use the Bluetooth device, but the error keep shown up in the end of the upgrading command line.
