Is there a driver for Realtek 8811CU USB NIC that works in Ubuntu Budgie 24.04 installer?
Does a driver exist for Realtek 8811CU USB NIC? One that actually functions inside the installer? I haven't tried yet but I have tried 22.04 and 23.10 all to no avail. There's no driver for it on github with the support for Ubuntu 24.04. I just want linux instead of windows and my favorite tools back.

If you have not tried I suggest that maybe you should before asking a question. There may be no need for it.

If there isn't a driver built in or it doesn't work you could compile your own from source. I think the one you want is listed on site pointed to be https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516979/rtl8812au-dkms-error-during-upgrade-ubuntu-24-04/1517093#1517093

@DavidDE There's no driver of any kind.

@david Can't use that one, I would need to install a significantly older kernel which doesn't have some hardware support I need.

@DaeDae311 (modified) I am using a similar one 8821au-20210708 tested for kernel 6.5 and supported for 'Kernels: 5.12 - 6.10 (community support)' and it still works for current 6.8. I assume you would use 8821cu-20210916 tested for kernel 6.2 and supported for 'Kernels: 5.12 - 6.11 (community support)'  Might be worth a try? (I am using 24.04) –

@david I found that it was actually supported within the kernel. Not sure of the specific, but it does work for 6.8 and up from what I know. Unsure why there's no documentation on it, but it is useable right away on distributions like Ubuntu, Arch Linux, etc.
