TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Plus driver for Ubuntu 24.04
My motherboard doesn't have a wifi adapter, so I'm using a tplink. On windows it worked with no problems, however, when i tested it on Ubuntu it didn't work. Searching on internet I found some steps to install the driver to get it working:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms git
sudo apt install build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install

After all that it should be working, but it's not what happened. I still cannot connect to the internet via wifi.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (kernel 6.8.0-31-generic).

What messages resulted from the listed commands? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].

@Marco Ortiz If the driver you have chosen is failing to build or install (see first comment) then you could try the driver pointed to by the answer at  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516979/rtl8812au-dkms-error-during-upgrade-ubuntu-24-04/1517093#1517093 which is working for me on 24.04 kernel 6.8*.

I couldn't get the aircrack ones to work in 24.04 with the AC600.
However, these ones work for me:
https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708

The AirCrack module worked on the previous Kernel version used in KDE neon 5. With KDE neon 6, the module, even if built and installed successfully, started returning the following in /var/log/syslog: BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference with a stack trace including rtl8812_HalDmWatchDog+0x56/0x70 [88XXau]. So, it's probably a bug which appeared due to updates, where the communication with the device and Kernel in the current module implementation is malformed. The module you suggested works like a charm - replaced the lovely AirCrack's. Thank you and the module contributors heartfelt! ✨

Yes 8821au-20210708 is working!! https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708
I update to 24.04. Difficult. I was so bad that I deleted the dual partition and bye bye Windows for a clean install. Ethernet wire for Internet. Hours and a nightmare to fix this problem. I followed at least 12 different procedures. Nothing! I installed first rtl8812au and nothing! I was thinking in buying another adapter or, even, quit.  Finally I arrived here.
The process to install the driver successfully for a non-pro is far from being easy. So, you downloaded the driver 8821au-20210708 and I went to the README (yes, I know, but again, we are non-pro, to follow the guide is not for common users). My biggest recognition and credit to the people who make the driver pack and the README. You are stars!
So, the problem is that there are too many steps involved in a highly changing environment, if you make something wrong, it will not work. So follow README step by step. If you do not know where to find it, after downloading the driver pack, go to Files and find the folder of the pack, the README is inside. Many places you can be wrong if not done properly.
It works, Ubuntu 24.04 with TP-Link AC600 wireless adapter using 8821au-20210708 driver.
Good luck!
