TP-Link Archer T2U Plus driver issue on Ubuntu 22.04 and Kernel 6.8.0-40-generic
I have a TP-Link Archer T2U Plus wifi adapter, and when I go to settings it says that there is not wifi adapter detected.
The usb port recognizes the adapter
../~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link Archer T2U PLUS [RTL8821AU]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa67 Areson Technology Corp 2.4G Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Here is my Ubuntu and kernel versions
../~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

../~$ uname -r
6.8.0-40-generic

also running the command sudo dkms status shows that I have an rtl8821au driver already installed
../~$ sudo dkms status
rtl8821au/5.12.5.2, 6.8.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed

I already followed the steps in https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708, but it does not seem to work still.
Any guidance on how to get the wifi adapter working would be much appreciated!

I suspect the driver you have is not working. See the answer in the following link for a similar supported alternative. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516979/rtl8812au-dkms-error-during-upgrade-ubuntu-24-04/1517093#1517093 Don't for get to remove the old one before installing.

It turns like what @david said, that the drivers were out of date. I eventually just searched on Amazon for a different wireless adapter that already has linux support. I found a really great list here https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi that outlines which products have up-to-date linux drivers.

Probably your driver is no longer supported for the current kernel.
The following link has supported source for your driver rtl8821au (bottom right) you are inquiring about: -
https://github.com/morrownr
Kernels: 5.4 - 5.11 (Realtek)
Kernels: 5.12 - 6.10 (community support)

22.04 is @ kernel 6.8.0.40 currently (28/08/24) (or there about)
